# Inserting into DataTable and DataRow : Index out of range

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

Good day Stack Exchange. This is my first post here. I need your help in this problem I got with DataTable and Datarow. Here's the error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

^This occurs and points to dataGridView1[0] index

Here is my code:

```
static DataTable dtTest = GetTable();

    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        //added 4 columns with an incremental id

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrement = true;
        dt.Columns.Add("item");
        dt.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(decimal));
        return dt;
    }

    private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             //added 3 rows to hold data to be inserted to DataTable

            DataRow myRow;

            myRow = dt.NewRow();
            myRow["item"] = txtItem.Text;
            myRow["qty"] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQty.Text);
            myRow["amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmount.Text);
            dtTest.Rows.Add(myRow);

            refreshItemGrid();
    }

    private void refreshItemGrid()
    {
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;             // ID
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "ITEM";         // item 
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "QUANTITY";     // qty
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "AMOUNT";       // amount
    }
```

Where am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for the help. Cheers!

Comment: Where do you bind the dtTest to the dataGridView1? Until you bind them there are no columns to use in the dataGridView

Comment: I have previously tried "dataGridView1.DataSource = dtTest" to bind my datagridview but it's the same error

Comment: And what is the value of the property AutoGenerateColumns? It should be set to True (this is the default but let's check it...), and by the way, I suppose that it is a typo, but you can't create a NewRow from a table and the add to another table

Comment: How do i upvote your comment Steve? it solved it! thanks, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is due to the missing binding between the `dataGridView1` and the table created in the `GetTable` method. So you need to put somewhere the line

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = <table_returned_from_GetTable_call>;
```

I put this line in this way because it is not clear from your code above where this line should be added. Surely the call to `bntInsert` click event need to have this in place before.

In addition to this, you should be sure that the property **AutoGenerateColumns** is set to True.
(This is the default, but given the context it is possible that you have set it to false inadvertently). Finally (and this is probably just a typo) you need to fix

```
 myRow = dtTest.NewRow();
```

Comment: the answer was at AutoGenerateColumns to true. spasibo.